SwiftPlaygroundsの解答の文法に関する質問
MacのSwift Playgroundというappleがデベロッパーのアプリです。
このアプリは、キャラクターを操作してジェムを集めるというゲームを通して、if文や、変数などの基本的な文法が学べるというものです。
下の写真のステージでwhileを使わずに書いた自分のコードではジェムを全て集めきることができました。
しかし、集めた後もキャラクターが動いてしまうプログラムであったためクリアできなかったです。（サブタスクである集めたジェムの数を変数に記録するというタスクもできていました）
Swiftにおけるwhileの使い方は知っていたので、早く残りの文法を学びたかったので解答を写すことにしました。
下の写真にある、右下のコードが解答です。
swiftでのコーディングは初めてな私でも文法的に不備があるのでは？と思いましたが、appleが作ったアプリでコードのミスがあるはずがない、swiftではwhileの下にインデントせずにif文を書くものなのか、、、と解答を写しました。

案の定、クリアできるどころかキャラは動くことさえしませんでした。
その時は文法エラーは出ていなかったので、whileの後にインデントせずにif文を書くのが間違っていたわけではないのでしょうか。
インデントしたとしてwhileにwhileを重ねているのもおかしいような気がします。
どこに文法のミスがあったのか、ご助言お願いします。
またこのステージの解答も添えていただけると幸いです。

